# RequireJs serving both .ts and .js file to browser

Tags: typescript, requirejs

Following are the files are present in my ASP.NET Core Project.

`greet.ts`

```
export class WelcomMesssage {
name: string;
constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
}
say(): void {
    console.log("Welcome " + this.name);
}
}
```

`GreetExample.ts`

```
import * as greet from "./greet";
export function Test(): void {
    let g = new greet.WelcomMesssage("Bhavesh");
    g.say();
}
```

`main.ts`

```
require.config({
     baseUrl:'Scripts'
});
require(['GreetExample'], (GreetExample) => { GreetExample.Test() });
```

`index.html` File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>index</title>
    <script data-main="Scripts/main" src="lib/requirejs/require.js" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

When I looked into sources in Chrome debug tools, my web app was serving both .ts and .js files.

[image]

Why is it serving both .ts and .js file? I am minifying all the javascript generated by .ts files and putting them all in `wwwroot/build` folder. How do I use this minified files with requirejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequireJS is not responsible for *serving* anything to the browser. It is the job of your server to serve files. Additionally, RequireJS won't fetch anything you don't explicitly require it to fetch. If you ask it to fetch a `.js` file generated from a TypeScript compilation, it won't seek the `.ts`.

Your browser may fetch more files than those you ask RequireJS to load, or it may *show files that are not even served by your server*. For instance, if you open the debugger in Chrome to look at source files, and your JS files were compiled with the TypeScript compiler with `inlineSourceMap` and `inlineSources` turned on, the debugger will show the `.ts` files that correspond to the `.js` files. Even if you deployed only the `.js` files to the server, the debugger will show the `.ts` files, reconstructed from the inline sources you asked the compiler to include in the generated code.

Another scenario is if you have a reference to an external sourcemap. The browser will fetch that map when you look at the `.js` file. If you trace network requests, you'll set a `GET` request for the map.

Comment: Thank you for reply Louis. I had `sourceMap` set to true in `tsconfig.json` file which was generating `.map` files and as you mentioned in your answer, chrome debugger might be using this `.map` file to generate `.ts` files. So I switch `sourceMap` to false and it is no longer showing `.ts` files.